# PHP - Replace part of a string

Tags: php, regex, replace

Here is my code!

```
$Find = array('hardwareSet[articles][(.*)]');
$Replace   = array('hardwareSetRAM');

$RAMBOX = str_replace($Find, $Replace, $RAMBOX);
```

The whole text is like this: `hardwareSet[articles][RANDOMnumberHERE]`

The second `[]` always has different numbers. I want `hardwareSet[articles][WhatEverNumberIsHere]` to be changed to a string looking like `hardwareSetRAM`.

How can I do that, can you help me out?

Comment: I have the feeling somehow you're asking in a roundabout way for someone to point out that there's another replace function `preg_replace` which "Perform[s] a regular expression search and replace" which is what you want apparently.

Comment: Stupid question, but how is this "unclear what you're asking" when there are 4 answers? Obviously it was clear to some people. I'm voting to reopen.

Comment: @Mike, I think the problem is that the question is basically "can you fix my code?", which is not a useful question.

Comment: @Ian In that case they should have voted it "too broad".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a regular expression. `str_replace` will only replace static values.

```
$RAMBOX = 'hardwareSet[articles][123]';
$Find = '/hardwareSet\[articles\]\[\d+\]/';
$Replace   = 'hardwareSetRAM';
$RAMBOX = preg_replace($Find, $Replace, $RAMBOX);
```

Output:

> hardwareSetRAM

The `/`s are [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). The `\`s are escaping the `[]`s. The `\d` is a number. The `+` says one or more numbers.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/jS6nO9/1

If you want to capture the number put the `\d+` inside a capture group, `()`. That will be referenced as `$1` in the replace value.

Comment: How is it not working? https://eval.in/468312

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using RegExp, use `preg_replace`

```
preg_replace('/hardwareSet\[articles\]\[.*\]/', 'hardwareSet[articles][hardwareSetRAM]', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is strange.

If you know start of the string, you can only generate new string:

```
$str = 'hardwareSet[articles][' . $newValue . ']';
```

But if you don't know any of the part in string, you can use this code:

```
<?php

$Find = array('hardwareSet[articles][(.*)]');
$Replace   = 'hardwareSetRAM';

$RAMBOX = preg_replace('~^(.+)\[(.+)\]\[(.+)\]$~', '$1[$2][' . $Replace . ']', $Find);

var_dump($RAMBOX);
```

In this code doesn't meter any of parts in the string

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    $t ='hardwareSet[articles][RANDOMnumberHERE]';
    echo replace_between($t, 'hardwareSet[articles][', ']', 'hardwareSetRAM');

    function replace_between($str, $needle_start, $needle_end, $replacement) {
        $pos = strpos($str, $needle_start);
        $start = $pos === false ? 0 : $pos + strlen($needle_start);

        $pos = strpos($str, $needle_end, $start);
        $end = $pos === false ? strlen($str) : $pos;

        return substr_replace($str, $replacement, $start, $end - $start);
    }
```